# Compilation of CHIBIOS on STM32F4-Discovery with CooCox

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32f4discovery

I am rather painfully new at compilation for ARM.

I started by using CooCox. After creating a project, I added all the CHIBIOS include paths to the project. My code itself is the default Chibios example code for the stm32F4 discovery.

On compilation, I get a output file with nothing in it.

However, if I deselect "discard unused sections" in the link configuration, I get the following:

`GCC HOME: C:\CooCox\CoIDE\GCC\bin
compile:
    [mkdir] Skipping C:\CooCox\Code\Test3\test3_Flash\Debug\bin because it already exists.
    [mkdir] Skipping C:\CooCox\Code\Test3\test3_Flash\Debug\obj because it already exists.
       [cc] 2 total files to be compiled.
       [cc] arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Wall -ffunction-sections -g -O0 -c -DSTM32F407VG -DSTM32F4XX -IC:\CooCox\Code\Test3 -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\boards\st_stm32f4_discovery -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\ports\common\armcmx -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\ports\gcc\armcmx -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\hal\src -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\various -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\kernel\src -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\ports\gcc\armcmx\stm32f4xx\ld -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\hal\platforms\stm32 -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\demos\armcm4-stm32f407-discovery -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\hal\platforms\stm32\rtcv1 -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\hal\include -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\ports\gcc\armcmx\stm32f4xx -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\hal\platforms\stm32\usbv1 -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\hal\platforms\stm32f4xx -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\test -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2 -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\ports\common\armcmx\cmsis\include -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\hal\platforms\stm32\gpiov2 -IC:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\kernel\include C:\CooCox\Code\Test3\main.c C:\CooCox\Code\Test3\syscalls\syscalls.c
       [cc] In file included from C:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\os\hal\include/hal.h:39:0,
       [cc]                  from C:\CooCox\Code\Test3\main.c:29:
       [cc] C:\CooCox\Code\chibitest\chibios_2.4.2\boards\st_stm32f4_discovery/board.h:57:0: warning: "STM32F4XX" redefined [enabled by default]
       [cc] <command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
       [cc] C:\CooCox\Code\Test3\main.c: In function 'Thread1':
       [cc] C:\CooCox\Code\Test3\main.c:189:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
       [cc] Starting link
       [cc] arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Wl -nostartfiles -g -Wl,-Map=test3_Flash.map -O0 -lgcc -lc -lm -lnosys -LC:\CooCox\CoIDE\workspace\test3_Flash -Wl,-TC:\CooCox\CoIDE\workspace\test3_Flash/arm-gcc-link.ld -g -o test3_Flash.elf ..\obj\main.o ..\obj\syscalls.o
       [cc] ..\obj\main.o: In function`pwmpcb':

```
   [cc] C:\CooCox\Code\Test3/main.c:127: undefined reference to `ADCD1'
```

After the last line, pretty much every single variable in the files is listed the same way.

Now I know my problem is linker related, but I am unsure where to fix it.

Perhaps I need to approach it a different way?
Fixing the two above warnings (commenting and adding return respectively) does not fix the issue.

As a bit of background, I am looking to use Chibios to drive a camera and other devices attached to stm32F4. If CooCox turns out to simply be a pain, I can switch to something more makefile friendly (there is no way to import makefiles!)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

As an open source toolchain for developing with the F4 & chibios you can try chibistudio:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/chibios/files/ChibiStudio/

I have been using it for a while and I'm really satisfied with it.